# Правильно ли оформлены предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Вспомните Стива Джобса, который, как бы опровергая известное «спрос рождает предложение», говорил о том, что обратное тоже имеет место. Людям сначала надо показать предлагаемое, что он и делал и получал спрос.

Изначально здесь было два двоеточия в одном предложении и потом я добавила местоимение "он".

Answer (score 2):

"Показать предлагаемое" вполне допустимо в профессиональном тексте (например, в маркетинговом): я предлагаю вам купить столы, но не показываю их, а хорошо бы и показать.

Итог:

*Вспомните Стива Джобса, который в противовес известному «Спрос рождает предложение» говорил, что обратное тоже возможно. Людям сначала надо показать предлагаемое, что он и делал, в результате получая спрос.*

1. Как бы опровергая = как бы беременна. Варианты: в противовес; опровергая; не соглашаясь...
2. Известное «спрос рождает предложение» - лучше с прописной, так как закавыченный текст образует законченное предложение.
3. "Имеет место" - ужОс, так и хочется написать "имеет место быть".
4. "Говорил о том, что" - говорил, что... (краткость - сестра таланта).
5. "Что он и делал и получал спрос" - одновременность действия: что он и делал, формируя таким образом спрос; последовательность событий: что он и делал, а в результате получал спрос. Я выбрала средний вариант: что он и делал, в результате получая спрос.

Answer (score 1):

"Показать предлагаемое" – очень плохо.

"Он делал предложение и в результате имел спрос". Если уж продолжать игру словами "спрос" и "предложение"

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Людям сначала надо показать нечто новое, что он и делал, и в результате получал спрос.